# performance difference between querying a database or searching an array?

Tags: database, performance

I have a suggestion feature that takes what the user has written so far (say "abc") and offers suggestions based on a list of 20k+ items.

Now I don't want anything fancy, it just searches for strings that begin with "abc", and thats what I want.

My question is: is there a huge difference in performance if the list of items is hard-written in a PHP array, against an SQL db?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends. In most cases, database performs faster, but take into account that the most expensive operation is disk IO, and having data hardcoded in php array removes needs of reading data from hard drive. So if you you database has a high level of fragmentation, you may have a bit better performance with sequential search over array.
However, when it comes to large amount of data, db will do the job better.

Comment: Why are dbs better even on a non-index column search? is this because they use multi-threads, and could normal linear searches on array achieve faster results if they use multi-threads given that the size of the data can fit in main memory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Complexity of searching in database by indexed column should be about log(n), simply searching array will be n (unless you are using binsearch on sorted array). Anyway RMDBS will do it much quicker since it have strongly optimized code for doing such tasks and PHP is scripting language using references everywhere(very slow).